# Run external catch from nested try

Tags: javascript, nested, try-catch

```
inProgress = false;

//async function which send value to device
function send(_callback){ 
   try{ 
      // code that generate error
      _callback(); 
   }catch(err){
      console.log("_callback doesn't start");
   }
}

function prepare_to_send(){
   try{
       inProgress= true; 
       send(function(){ 
          send(function(){ // isn't runned, because was err inside send
             inProgress = false;
          })
       });
   }catch(err){
      inProgress = false;
   }
}
```

As in the code above. 
If was error in send function, prepare_to_send function don't change back global variable InProgress to false, beacuse _callback and catch from prepare_to_send are not runned.

Is this possible without changing send function?

Comment: No, you need to change send function in one way or another. Though you really should re-evaluate your entire approach

Comment: You might return a value from send function and act accordingly.

Comment: you probably want the send function to use two callbacks, a success callback and an error callback. Call the error callback from the catch block and the success callback from the try block after the code that can throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

If `_callback` isn't an asynchronous function you can re-throw the error, or even a new one :

```js
inProgress = false;

//async function which send value to device
function send(_callback) {
  try {
    // code that generate error
    _callback();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("_callback doesn't start");
    throw err;
  }
}

function prepare_to_send() {
  try {
    inProgress = true;
    send(function() {
      throw 'error';
    });
  } catch (err) {
    inProgress = false;
    console.log(err);
  }
}

prepare_to_send();
```

But if `_callback` is asynchronous as you seem to state, then you'll have to deal with promises all the way, *ie.* adapt the whole code. You also can add an error callback as stated in comment section :

```js
inProgress = false;

//async function which send value to device
function send(_callback, errorCallback) {
  // code that generate error
  _callback(errorCallback);
}

function prepare_to_send() {
  inProgress = true;
  send(function(errorCallback) { // Your callback have to call another function on error
    try {
      throw 'error';
    } catch (err) {
      errorCallback();
    }
  }, function() {
    inProgress = false;
    console.log('error occured');
  });
}

prepare_to_send();
```